# Constructor Troubles in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, constants

I've found a lot of similar question on here, but none that helped me, so here it is. I have the following 3 files; The first is the Includes.h:

```
#ifndef INCLUDES_H_
#define INCLUDES_H_

#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<array>
#include<vector>
#include<chrono>
#include<iostream>
#include<random>
#include<iterator> 
#include<utility>
#include<functional>
#include<math.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

#endif /* INCLUDES_H_ */
```

The second is Attack.h

```
#ifndef ATTACK_H_
#define ATTACK_H_

#include "Includes.h"

class Attack {

public:
  //constructor random attack/key of dimension, nrofkeys                                
  Attack(const int& d,const int& k);
  //constructor given attack/key                                                        
  Attack(const string& attckRes,const vector<int>& corKey);
  //deconstructor                                                                       
  virtual ~Attack();
  //data management                                                                     
  vector<int> getKey() const;
  double getpKey() const;
  vector<vector<double>> getPMF() const;
  vector<vector<int>> getkPMF() const;
  //print stuff                                                                         
  void printPMF();
  void printkPMF();
  void printpKey();
  void printKey();

 protected:
  double pKey;
  vector<int> key;
  vector<vector<double>> PMF;
  vector<vector<int>> kPMF;
};
#endif /* ATTACK_H_ */
```

And finally the class Attack.cpp (I leave out some of the functionalities):

```
#include "Attack.h"

//Constructor random attack                                                             
Attack::Attack(const int& d,const int& k) : pKey(1.0){
  random_device rd;
  mt19937 el(rd());
  uniform_real_distribution<> urd(0,1);
  double count = 0.0;
  vector<double> temp;
  vector<int> temp2;
 // more code
}
Attack::Attack(const string& attckRes,const vector<int>& corKey) : key(corKey),pKey(1.0    ) {
  string line;
  char str[50];
  ifstream data(attckRes);
  double val;
  int n;
  int sub;
  int count = 1;
  double count2=0.0;
  vector<double> temp;
 // more code
}

/* more code
```

I then (in foo.cppp) run:

```
#include "Attack.h"

int main(){
   Attack myAt((int) 4,(int) 8);
   myAt.printPMF();
   myAt.printkPMF();
   myAt.printKey();
   myAt.printpKey();
   return 0;
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
g++ -c Attack.cpp  -std=c++11
Attack.cpp:10:1: error: prototype for ‘Attack::Attack(const int&, const int&)’ does not match any in class ‘Attack’
 Attack::Attack(const int& d,const int& k) : pKey(1.0){
 ^
Attack.h:12:7: error: candidates are: Attack::Attack(const Attack&)
 class Attack {
       ^
Attack.h:18:3: error:                 Attack::Attack(const string&, const std::vector<int>&)
   Attack(const string& attckRes,const vector<int>& corKey);
   ^
Attack.h:16:3: error:                 Attack::Attack(int, int)
   Attack(const int& d,const int& k);
   ^
make: *** [Attack.o] Error 1
```

The mistake is somewhere in the constructors, but I cannot figure out where. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Why are you using `const int&`? Just use `int`

Comment: Looks as if the header declares `Attack(int, int)` and not `Attack(const int&, const int&)`. Are you sure it's including the correct one (and the correct version)? And anyway, `const int&` has 0 advantages over `int`, and could even be slower.

Comment: on the bright side, I get an: `/tmp/ccgQdxOC.o:1.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to 'vtable for Attack'`, which I havent seen before.

Comment: Re: `(int)4` - `4` has type `int`, so the cast doesn't do anything.

Comment: This was a second try, changing the const int& to int gave the same errors. Hower then I had 4 instead of (int) 4 and it works now!

Comment: @RichardPlunkett: That would be because the destructor is declared virtual but not defined. GCC emits the vtable in the same translation unit as the first non-pure, non-inline virtual function, if such a thing is declared.

Comment: The error message you gave above does not match the source you provided.  Change both the header and the .cpp file to take `Attack(int d, int k)` for that first constructor and it should start working.

Comment: @Mike ok, now compiles with gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)

Comment: Don't put `using namespace std` in a header file.

Comment: try change `Attack::Attack(const int& d,const int& k) : pKey(1.0)` to `Attack::Attack(const int& d,const int& k)`